# Netsuite UI Modification with SuiteScript in Purchase Order Entry

Tags: user-interface, netsuite

**NetSuite** currently has the ability to "COPY PREVIOUS" during the line item entry on a Purchase Order, but upon change of the item number, the system will overwrite the description and unit price with the defaults from the Item Master table. Can somebody assist me with a challenge in SuiteScript in which I need to address the previous record in a scrollable table ? i.e. Line 2 on a Purchase Order during Data Entry. How do I refer to the previous line in SuiteScript? I would need to execute this code after the user selected a different Item Number.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a client-side script, particularly in the Field Change function.

This code ain't perfect but should help you get started, make sure that you deployed this in the Purchase Order transactions:

```
function fieldChanged(type, name, linenum){
    if(type == 'item' && name == 'item')
    {
        {
            var currIndex = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemIndex('item');  //Get the current index, this is the total count of line items in the transaction
            if(currIndex > 1) //You have to have at least two line items to be able to refer to the previous line item
            {
                var prev = currIndex - 1;
                var itemNo  = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'item', prev); //This it the item number from the previous line item..Do whatever you want from here....
            }
        }
    }

}
```